# Как реализовать нажатие на определенные картинки на веб странице?

Tags: python, selenium

как можно реализовать с помощью Python автокликер который будет нажимать на определенные картинки (все это на веб странице)? (как должно работать: сохраняются 9 картинок, далее 6 из них исключаются для нажатия и только 3 должны прожиматься). Так же стоит отметить, что их координаты всегда меняется.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поиск по CSS селектору

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector().click()
```

Поиск по имени

```
driver.find_element_by_name().click()
```

Поиск по классу элемента

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name().click()
```

Поиск используя XPath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath().click()
```